# Event Grid Subscription: Terraform missing "Enable Advanced Filtering on arrays" property

Tags: terraform, azure-eventgrid, azure-rm

I was checking the [event-grid-subscription](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/eventgrid_event_subscription#advanced_filter) to find a property which is likely to be a boolean type that I can see in the portal below `Enable Advanced Filtering on arrays` However I couldn't find the exact property in the tf docs.

[image]

Am I missing any properties here or the tf module itself doesn't have these features yet?

Comment: You've linked directly to the parameter for configuring the advanced filtering in the resource. What is missing from what you want there?

Comment: our client created the grid sub through portal for the dev environment and we want to replicate the same configurations in qa/prod through terraform and not via portal. The sub which was created by our client has enabled this value -`Enable Advanced Filtering on arrays`. so I'm checking how to enable this from terraform

Comment: If there's nothing set in the filters like in the above screenshot then it's not actually doing anything. The checkbox there just enables the rules set in the above table. So you don't need to do anything to set them the same and can just have the Terraform created version leave it unchecked.

Comment: I thought the same, However, I'll confirm this with the client, specifically why he enabled this without adding any filter, (which is not making sense) and get back to you

Comment: The property *EnableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays* is supported on API versions newer than 2020-10-15-preview, so you should use the restapi provider in the terraform to handle the new features of the AEG advanced filtering.

Comment: Thanks @RomanKiss could you please convert your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property EnableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays is supported on API versions newer than 2020-10-15-preview, so you should use the restapi provider in the terraform to handle the new features of the AEG advanced filtering.

Have a look at more details for [Event Subscriptions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/version2020-10-15-preview/event-subscriptions/update) using the REST API.

Comment: Opened the feature request on tf repo - https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/12563

Answer (score 0):

Just an Update that my [PR for this enhancement is merged](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/12609)

You have to use version `2.69 .0` and above to use this property

```
  required_providers {
    azurerm = "~> 2.69.0"
  }
```